# Obtain Postgres binaries for FreeBSD

Tags: postgresql, installation

[I can find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=postgresql&stype=name&sektion=databases) the latest [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) versions such as 11.1 as source code configured to be downloaded and built for [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) amongst the [Ports Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ports_collection).

I cannot find compiled binaries for the latest versions of Postgres amongst the FreeBSD Packages.

```bsd
pkg search postgresql
```

…returns items for Postgres 9.3 through 9.6, and version 10.5. But I see no entries for Postgres versions 11 or 11.1.

➥ Is this a new normal, not pre-compiling Postgres 11 for FreeBSD? Is compiling from the Ports Collection the usual way to install Postgres on BSD?

➥ Am I looking in the wrong place or in the wrong way?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, but I included that link in my Question. I’m looking for the precompiled binaries, not the source-code bundles.

Comment: I'm sorry if I missunderstood your question but it seems to me you can find the PostgreSQL 11.1 packages for FreeBSD here : https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=postgresql&stype=name&sektion=databases

Comment: @Arkhena In FreeBSD, the Ports Collection you referred to is for source code to be downloaded and compiled into a binary executable. In contrast, Packages and the `pkg` tool are for downloading pre-built binary executables. See sections 4.4 and 4.5 of the Handbook.